# A question on two complement sets, which are subsets of a given set $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have a set $X$ and $M$, which is a subset of $X$. There is a unique complement of $M$ with respect to $X$:
$$
M^c = X\setminus M =\{x\in X : x \notin M\}
$$
But what if we would have another subset $A$ of $X$ and a complement of $A$: 
$$
A^c = X\setminus A=\{x\in X: x \notin A\}
$$
Would the complement of $M$ now be $\{ x\in X: x\in A \wedge x\notin M\}$?

Comment: No. The definition of $M^{c}$ doesn't change because there are other subsets. What you have described is the intersection of $A$ and $M^c$.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Oh, I meant Mc = {x∈X: x∈A Λ x∈Ac Λ x∉M}. I have to see it visualized with two sets, then I wouldve understand it

Comment: @JohnDouma Which is the same as $A\setminus M$.

Comment: $x$ cannot be in in both $A$ and $A^c$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I do not really understand it... What would Ac and Mc look like?

Comment: Here is an example.  Let our universal set be $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Let $M=\{1\}$ and $A=\{1,2\}$.  We would have $M^c = \{2,3,4\}$ and $A^c=\{3,4\}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma You are right, I see it now. I am really confused if the case with two subsets of X with a comlpement of each subset appears

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Are you saying you would prefer I be more brief? :-)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the example! I trie to visualize it!

Comment: Think of each subset/complement pair as a partition of the set. There are many ways to cut a cake in two.

Comment: @JohnDouma I will! Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @D.Dave That ${}^c$-notation depends on the universal set of the context.  Take the sets of JMoravitz’ example.  If $M$ was the universal set, then $A^c=\emptyset$, if it was $A$, the $M^c=\{2\}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Not all, but it helps to see the same thing from a different point of view.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Did you notice the smile emoticon? I wasn't being serious and yes, I agree. It does help to see things in multiple ways.

Comment: Is there any visualisation to keep it better in mind, like union of sets or the intersection?

Comment: I understood it now, thanks guys

Comment: I'm completely confused as to why you think sets A and M and $A^c$ and $M^c$ would give a tinker's fig about each other at all?  Let X be all Natural numbers.  Let M = all the perfect squares and let A = the numbers with the digit 7 somewhere in it.  So $M^c$ is all the numbers that are not perfect squares.  "But what about the numbers with the digit 7?" you seem to be asking.  Well, what *about* them.  They have nothing to do with the perfect squares.  A and M care sod-all about each other.

Comment: @fleablood I missunderstood it, now I understand it, I hope so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is not relevent to $M$ at all and need not be mentioned at all.  They have nothing to do with each other.

Let $X = ${swans, snowmen, crows, coal, bluebirds, igloos, apartments, blueberries}

Let $A = $ things that are white = {swans, snowmen, igloos}.  Then $A^c$ = things that are not white= {crows, coal, bluebirds, apartments, blueberries}.

Let $M = $ places you can live ={igloos, apartments}.  Then $M^c$ = = things you can't live in ={swans, snowmen, crows, coal, bluebirds, blueberries}

Let $D = $ birds = {swans, crows, bluebirds}.  Then $D^c = $things that are not birds = { snowmen,  coal,  igloos, apartments, blueberries}.

Figuring out $A^c$ is has nothing to do with $M$ or $D$ whatsoever.